# how can i do redirect after ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

```
`@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete.do")
    public String delete(int projectNo) {
        int result=service.delete(projectNo);
        return "admin/manage";
    }`

`$.ajax({
                                    url : "/delete.do",
                                    data:{projectNo:projectNo},
                                    success : function(result){
                                        window.location.href = result.redirect;                                     
                                    },
                                    error : function(){
                                        alert("error");
                                    }
                                });`
```

in this ajax, i got "admin/manage" as  result.

this ajax is written in admin/manage.

i want to do redirect to admin/manage after ajax but i don't know how to do

Comment: What is the error? Any error in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work correctly, if not, try to append `/` before `result.redirect` to redirect same domain

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/delete.do",
    data: { projectNo: projectNo },
    success: function (result) {
        window.location.href = "/"+ result.redirect;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```